# SQL statement error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054, mysql-error-1248

```
mysql> Select Emp_B AS Total
    -> From (Select Sum(mines.NoOfWorkers) AS Emp_B from mines);
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

mysql> Select Emp_B AS Total
    -> From (Select Sum(mines.NoOfWorkers) from mines) AS Emp_B;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Emp_B' in 'field list'
```

I am having some problem with this SQL statement. Any assistance will be mose appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Emp_B AS Total
From (Select Sum(mines.NoOfWorkers) AS Emp_B from mines) x;
```

As the error states *`Every derived table must have its own alias`*
Just give it an alias, like `x` above. OR `AS x`, but the `AS` word is optional.

Or why alias it twice...

```
Select Total
From (Select Sum(mines.NoOfWorkers) AS Total from mines) x;
```

But since SUM gives you exactly one value, unless you have simplified the query from some larger one, this gives exactly the same result??

```
Select Sum(mines.NoOfWorkers) AS Total from mines;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you; however, if you're only doing this one sub select into a temp table it's kind of a waste to wrap it into another select but that's just IMHO.

```
Select Emp_B.sum From (Select Sum(mines.NoOfWorkers) as sum from mines) AS Emp_B;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select temp.total  
From 
  ( Select Sum(mines.NoOfWorkers) AS total 
    from mines
  ) AS temp
;
```